# relayouting UIPageViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uipageviewcontroller

I have a `UIPageViewController` with a view controllers called `UIZoomedImageViewController`. The `UIZoomedImageViewController` has different layout/positioning depending whether it's portrait or landscape. I have a method called `setViewBasedOnOrientation` that is called on `willAnimateToInterfaceOrientation`.

The issue I am having now however is that when I rotate the device and swipe to the next view controller it still has the size/layout of the previous orientation. How do I deal with this?